# How to set the pandas dataframe output in pycharm console up/down alignment?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pycharm

before I use

```
pd.set_option('expand_frame_repr', False)
```

the pandas output in pycharm console is up/down alignment in rows:
[alignment in rows](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rhn1v.jpg)

I want to see all of the dataframe columns, so I typed:

```
pd.set_option('expand_frame_repr', True)
```

but after this, the output of the dataframe in pycharm console is not up/down alignment in rows, it appears as this:
[dataframe in pycharm console is not up/down alignment in rows](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nLfNW.jpg)

the output is so terrible because the pandas dataframe is not alignment in rows, So how can I do to make the rows alignment again?

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same issue and just found out a way to solve it.

It is pretty straight forward, you need to uncheck the **Use Soft Wraps** button next to the Run Terminal in Pycharm. The button can be found here :

[image]

Below are two screenshots, one with the button checked and one without, we can then see that it corrects the issue!

[Screenshot : Use Soft Wraps **checked**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IlOJa.png)

[Screenshot : Use Soft Wraps **unchecked**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mDqpR.png)